# Build Factory in symfony

Tags: symfony, factory

hi I have class and I need to call to factory::create("name")

and then I have 3 classes with register method:
the factory should check wiche "name" is it and call to new from on of the classes

1- calls to Factory ::create("name")

2 - in the factory :
if(name = "x")
call to class x with paramters to construct
if (name ="y")
call to class Y with paramters to construct

and then in class x i need to invoke function register that do smth

my question is how to do that and how to update the service.yml accordingly

Comment: Could you show us whole your factory code?

Comment: @TomášVotruba how would that help and not just bloat the question? To me, this question comes down to "How do I call class x (with method Y and params XYZ)?". The manual and especially cookbook should sove this. So my question: What have you tried?